# How to solve xpath element that have special character

Tags: android, automated-tests, robotframework

I have meet the issue below . i try to click on element but in that xpath has containt **$** sign . and i got the message erorr:

**InvalidSelectorException: Message: Argument was an invalid selector (e.g. XPath/CSS).**

```
MyTest

      Start Application
      Input PIN     1235
      click element     xpath=//android.widget.HorizontalScrollView/android.support.v7.app.ActionBar$Tab[2]
```

Any Help please .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i change method by using like this

```
xpath=//android.widget.TextView[@text='Report']
```